# restore centos with recovered files

Tags: centos7, filesystems, gitlab

The file system of our centOS 7 was broken and could not be fixed (we tried lots of ways, all failed).

Luckily we got most of the files (maybe some is missing) with a disk recovery tool. Now we have files under `/` and `/home` in an USB hard disk.

We have `gitlab` and `testlink` installed on this centOS, and no backups. We want to get them back. Is it possible we can reinstall centOS with the same version and reuse the recovered files to get these two services back?

Comment: The partition failed because of a hard disk failure? if yes you can pay to have the platten read to restore as you have no backup. Way better than a recovery tool, but way cost more high than such tool.

Comment: yes, it's because of a hard disk failure. We already copy all the files to an external hard disk with a recovery tool. We are trying to find a low cost way to get everything back.